# C#, Unity IoC: Registering and resolving generic interfaces, good practices

Tags: c#, generics, architecture, unity-container

I wrote generic interface and over time, I started using it quite often. I had also idea to actually provide another generic interface, extending existing one.

Now, when I look into my Unity config (IoC framework is irrelevant here), it looks like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IConfigProvider<ICountryConfig>, CountryConfigProvider>();
container.RegisterType<IConfigProvider<ILanguageConfig>, LanguageConfigProvider>();

// IEnumerableConfigProvider<T> : IConfigProvider<IEnumerable<T>>
container.RegisterType<IEnumerableConfigProvider<ILocaleConfig>, LocaleConfigProvider>();

// ... repeat gazillion of times...
```

Using as dependency:

```
public LocaleResolver(IConfigProvider<ICountryConfig> countryConfigProvider, ...)
{
    // similar construct all over the place
}
```

Where `ICountryConfig`, `ILanguageConfig`, ... are interfaces describing database entities. Provider then takes care to provide correct entities to dependent components so access to storage is kept on own place.

Problem arise when I did little refactoring. I used accidentally parent interface instead of inherited one. It could be also quite fragile when using wrong type given to interface.

This led me to (obvious) idea creating yet another layer of interfaces to encapsulate concrete usage. That would solve issues described above, in other hand I will end up with trillion empty interfaces for every possible implementation.

```
// ICountryConfigProvider : IConfigProvider<ICountryConfig>
container.RegisterType<ICountryConfigProvider, CountryConfigProvider>();

// ILanguageConfigProvider : IConfigProvider<ILanguageConfig>
container.RegisterType<ILanguageConfigProvider, LanguageConfigProvider>();

// ILocaleConfigProvider : IEnumerableConfigProvider<ILocaleConfig>
container.RegisterType<ILocaleConfigProvider, LocaleConfigProvider>();
```

And it's cleaner usage:

```
public LocaleResolver(ICountryConfigProvider countryConfigProvider, ...)
{
    // ...
}
```

And what I'm looking for now is a good advice. Maybe I'm abusing IoC too much here. What is the best approach for mid-size project?

---

I'm aware this topic might end up with discussion rather than specific answer, I apologize for that dear StackOverflow.

Comment: Have you considered [registering open generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec13)?

Comment: Not really, can't imagine how that could help me in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each provider is a different concrete type then this approach, albeit verbose with the empty interfaces, is valid. Another, less verbose, solution would be generalise the configuration access so instead you have a single configuration 'service' that returns any one of many specific config blobs.

```
Eg configProvider.GetConfig<IWhateverConfig>();
```

This way you aren't flooding the container with lots of providers for what is essentially just retrieval of a certain type of property bag full of config. You would register a single config provider and under the covers map the config type to a config section. If you exposed this mapping functionality then config blobs can be registered in a more modular way at any point during application start up.

Comment: I like idea of having generic config provider, but in my case I failed to generalize it to level I could put it into single provider (e.g. my locale entity can actually fallback to record which is not linked to language)

Anyway, thanks for ensuring me I'm not doing something terribly wrong :)